# RSpec do not see updated attributes in factory_bot object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have report object called SiegeReport, that makes some calculations and returns integer object. When there is no **warrior** in the building, then **siege_ability** equals 0. The code itself is not important here, because it works fine in console and in application. Factories made by ***factory_bot*** work ok in all the other examples. I just have problem with testing the method:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Reports::SiegeReport do
  subject(:siege_report) { Reports::SiegeReport.new(building:    building).call }

  let(:building) { create(:building, granary: 100) }
  let(:clan) { create(:clan) }

    context 'with 1 infantry' do
      let(:warrior) { create(:warrior, clan_id: clan.id, building_id: building.id) }

      it 'returns 9' do
        expect(siege_report).to eq(9)
      end
    end
  end
```

RSpec returns:

```
Reports::SiegeReport siege ability with 1 infantry returns 9
      Failure/Error: expect(siege_report).to eq(9)

        expected: 9
            got: 0

        (compared using ==)
```

I checked it with ***pry*** and **warrior** object is valid, even **building.warriors** returns **warrior**, but in attributes number of warriors is still 0. The very same example works when i type it manually in console. How can I make ***RSpec*** update building attributes before testing?

Comment: Try `let!(:warrior) { create... }` since `let` is lazy-evaluated.

Comment: It works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution but is really not elegant:

```
it 'returns 9' do
  warrior.save
  expect(siege_report).to eq(9)
end
```

It works but it seems to me that it is not the proper way of testing. Still, I can't find a better solution.